# Custom cell factory for my JfxListView returns raw objects

Tags: java, javafx, custom-cell, openjfx

So my Custom cell factory should return two fields from the `Message` object, instead I get raw object in `ListView` [Output from ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OON2.png).

There is a code responsible for formatting two `Text` objects which gets values from fields in `Message` object.

```
   messageJFXListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Message>, ListCell<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Message> call(ListView<Message> param) {
                return new JFXListCell<Message>(){
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty || item == null || item.getMessage() == null) {
                            setText(null);
                        } else if(item.getNickname() == null) {
                            setText(item.getMessage()); // no formatting here yet
                        }
                        else{
                            Text nickname = new Text();
                            nickname.setStyle("-fx-fill: #424242;-fx-font-weight:bold;");
                            nickname.setText("<" + item.getNickname() + "> ");
                            Text message = new Text();
                            message.setText(item.getMessage());
                            getChildren().addAll(nickname,message);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }
```

After changing `getChildren().addAll(nickname,message);` to   `getChildren().addAll(new TextFlow(nickname,message));` it almost works but the style is not set on the nickname part and yeah raw object is still printed [The output from TextFlow change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS6JG.png).

**EDIT**:
Instead `getChildren().addAll()` I've used `setGraphic(new TextFlow(nickname,message));` and now formatting works.
[It really almost works like it should but raw object is still present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/854tb.png)

**EDIT2**:
I've added `setText(null);` at the begin of last else and it clears out the raw object and things works like they should right now but I won't mark this as answer because I feel like this is some kind of hack instead of proper solution.

**EDIT3**:
`Message` class, Observable list and JFXListView to make this case reproducible.

```
public class Message {
    private String nickname;
    private String message;

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public Message(String nickname, String message) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public Message() {
    }
    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    
}

public class MainWindowController   {
    @FXML
    public ObservableList<Message> messageObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    public JFXListView<Message> messageJFXListView;
}
```

Comment: [mcve] .. and stick to java naming conventions please!

Comment: .. and don't create a new node in each call of updateItem

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in JFoenix and seems like `setText(null)` is the only way to deal with it until they will fix it [Here is a ticket](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/817)